# Axonix (Mobiclix) Error code 999999

Tags: java, android, mobclix

I am implementing axonix Advertisement in android. I am right adding banner ads but I failed to load with error code 999999. I am not able to find error code description anywhere. If anybody come across this error please help me.

I have added code in manifest also.
I am adding my xml code and java implementation.

XML

```
<com.axonix.android.sdk.AxonixMMABannerXLAdView
    android:id="@+id/banner_adview"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tab_replace"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:tag="adspace" />
```

JAVA

```
AxonixMMABannerXLAdView adview_banner;

adview_banner = (AxonixMMABannerXLAdView) findViewById(R.id.banner_adview);
adview_banner.addAxonixAdViewListener(this);

adview_banner.getAd();
```

Also added methods that need to implemented for listening.